# Cannot find module \node_modules\expo\tools\LogReporter

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

After I [detached my react native app](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach) using `exp detach` I cannot run the app now using `exp start`

Anyone knows why I am getting this error:

> Cannot find module \node_modules\expo\tools\LogReporter.

I tried to update `exp` but still no luck.

Comment: did you npm install?